# asp.net core read config from appsettings and app service

Tags: asp.net-core

I am leaning asp.net core. i have a appsetting.json like below:

```
"Sites": {
  "SiteToWorkWith": {
    "SiteUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/pnp",
    "AADClientID": "xxx-xxx"
  },
}
```

And the project will be deployed on the Azure web app, then the customer will do some config on the Azure portal:
[image]

So how to get this config value? When I debug the program, it should get a value from appsetting.json. After publishing it should get value from the azure app.

In the formal asp.net framework, the variable will auto override in the web config file. but in asp.net core, what are the best practices?

Comment: Have you tried IConfiguration ?

Answer (score -2):

By default, if not configured in `Configuration` --> `Application settings`, everything is based on the configuration in `appsetting.json`.

If configured in `Application settings`, it will override the settings in appsetting.json.

**For example:** the value of `AADClientID` in `appsetting.json` is `test`. If it is not set in Application settings, the value obtained is `test`. If the value of `AADClientID` is set as `prod` in Application settings, the value obtained is `prod`.

We can get the application settings via rest api.
[Web Apps - List Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-application-settings?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)

[image]

[image]

Comment: but in appsettings.json file, AADClientID is in a section.  this is different from webconfig file.

Comment: @10120 In asp.net core, you don't need to mess with webconfig. Can you describe your problem in detail? Let us know exactly what you care about.

Comment: AADClientID is in a json section. if i directly configure it on Azure portal. will it auto override?